# how to set background color in ssrs parent report based on sub report background color

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas-2008

i have a 2 SSRS report using SSAS datasource. the way it is working is i have set some background color in 2nd report(sub report). what i wanted to do is to set background color of parent report based on its child report. i also have some hierarchy in parent report. so if a child node has red color(bad performance), i want to set same to parent node and its parent node (all the way to top most parent node). similarly if child has yellow but no red then set color of parent to yellow. if child doesn't have either red or yellow then set it to green.

how can i accomplish this in SSRS? i am using SSAS data source and have no idea of how i can determine by looking down in hierarchy and set color to parent node.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an extra field to your subreport's dataset?

If yes, then you can store the color value as a field (e.g. select *, 'SlateBlue' as ReportColor from YourTable) in your subreport's dataset and then reference it in the parent report by adding an expression to the BackgroundColor property.

Reference this post for accessing data from a subreport:
["SSRS Pull Variables Or Values From Sub Report Into Main Report"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279412/ssrs-pull-variables-or-values-from-sub-report-into-main-report)