# Pass sum from subreport to main report

Tags: rdlc, subreport

I have some customer information in main report and the account statement in sub report. The sub report have balance payment using RunninValue sum.

I need to show the balance payment in main report ie after the sub report table. How can i done this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an older post that explains how this can be achieved.

[Get data from a subreport into the main report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584509/get-data-from-a-subreport-into-the-main-report)

hope this can help you